# The application crashes after adding an animation to the tableview (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I'm trying to adding an animation to insertRows in a tableView when it loading, these are the animation func i created

```
func insertRowsMode3() {  
   insertRowMode3(ind: 0)   
}

func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {

   let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
   rows = ind + 1
   tableView.beginUpdates()
   tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
   tableView.endUpdates()

   guard ind < rows-1 else { return }
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.20) {

       self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
   }

}
```

these are my numberOfRow and numberOfSection

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    print("numberOfsection Call")
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print("numberOfRows Call")
    if places.count < self.numberPlaces {
       return  places.count
    }
    return self.numberPlaces
}
```

and this is my viewDidAppear

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        insertRowsMode3()    
}
```

numberPlaces, places and rows are Int variable, anyhow my application is crashing by this error

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0
>   into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the
>   update'" .

I have already tried to replace `rows` with `numberPlaces` but the application is still crashing, what i have to do to solve this problem?

Comment: post the crash log and cellforrow delegate function

Comment: of course it is crashing, you need to update your _model_ as well.

Comment: post cellForRow , do you insert new items in the model array as well ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You insert a new row there, but you did not update the model behind it. There is an incosistence after that - this method will have to update the number of rows too.

There has to be consistence between the model and the UI all the time! So if in time `n` the `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 3, and there are already 3 rows in `tableView`, then if in time `n + 1` you call `insertRows` to add a row, then you have to make sure that `numberOfRowsInSection` in that time will return 4 (that is 3 + 1, since you added 1 row). Therefore you will have to rework your whole code.

You can try something in the following manner:

```
// use an additional array for the rows to add them to tableView
var currentPlaces: [Place] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // use this as numberOfRowsInSection
    return currentPlaces.count
}

func insertRowMode3(ind: Int) {

    let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)

    // the model behind the tableView HAS to match the inserts/deletes
    currentPlaces.append(places[ind])
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)

    // use proper guard
    guard ind < places.count - 1 else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.20) {
        self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
    }
}
```

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I did on behalf of OP... :) As you deserves it.